# What are the similarities and differences between Stueckelberg mechanism and Higgs mechanism?

Tags: particle-physics, symmetry-breaking, higgs

What is the difference and similarities between the [Stueckelberg mechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stueckelberg_action) and the [Higgs mechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higgs_mechanism)?
They both make the gauge field massive. Is the Stueckelberg mechanism a special case about $U(1)$ gauge fields of the Higgs mechanism? Does there exist Spontaneously symmetry breaking in the Stueckelberg mechanism?

Comment: Yes, it's a special case, or a limit of it, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stueckelberg_action

Comment: This beautiful paper has some relevant comments: https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0304245v2.

Answer (score 11):

*There are no deep differences!* The Stueckelberg action is, in fact, a weird limit of the standard Goldstone sombrero potential, where, in effect, the self-coupling $\lambda$ is taken to infinity, while keeping the v.e.v. $\rm v$ fixed.

As a result, the $\sigma$ (analog of the Higgs) becomes infinitely massive and "decouples" (disappears from the spectrum), so 
it is dropped off the action, and only the massless goldston survives, Stueckelberg's celebrated scalar; this is the so-called $U(1)$ non-linear $\sigma$-model.

This could extend to nonabelian settings, cf. [Affine Higgs mechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higgs_mechanism#Affine_Higgs_mechanism)   ;  [Stueckelberg action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stueckelberg_action), but the surviving scalar sector is substantially messier, on account of the interactions among the goldstone modes that have not decoupled: the nonabelian $\sigma$-model is non-renormalizable.

In the unitary gauge, the resulting action is called the [Proca action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proca_action), and represents a pure massive "would be" gauge field, but, of course it is not manifestly gauge invariant. Unlike the case for non-abelian vector fields, quantum electrodynamics with a massive photon is, nevertheless, in fact, renormalizable!! How can this be? Well, it is actually a covert gauge invariant Higgs/Stueckelberg action, only the fact was not recognized! (Well, with the possible exception of [Ernst S in 1938](http://neo-classical-physics.info/uploads/3/0/6/5/3065888/stueckelberg_-_forces_of_interaction_ii.pdf)...)

Englert and Higgs et al simply recognized the generality and non-Abelian extensions of the fact, which made electroweak gauge theories a reality.